# How to proof that $\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} 1/i \ge 1+n/2$

Tags: inequality, induction

I had troubles trying to prove that for every $n\ge1$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n}\frac1i\ge 1+\frac n2$$

Can you give me a hint about the induction proof or show me in detail how can I prove it? I would appreaciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or without any explicit induction: the sum is
$$1+\Bigl(\frac12\Bigr)+\Bigl(\frac13+\frac14\Bigr)+\Bigr(\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18\Bigr)+\cdots+\Bigl(\frac1{2^{n-1}+1}+\cdots+\frac1{2^n}\Bigr)$$
which is greater than
$$1+\Bigl(\frac12\Bigr)+\Bigl(\frac14+\frac14\Bigr)+\Bigr(\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18\Bigr)+\cdots+\Bigl(\frac1{2^n}+\cdots+\frac1{2^n}\Bigr)\ .$$
Now (**hint**) think carefully about how many pairs of brackets there are, and how many terms there are inside each pair.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it as well! Thanks to all that answered too.

Answer (score 5):

By induction and for the inductive step we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac1i=\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n}}\frac1i+\sum_{i=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac1i\ge1+\frac n2+\underbrace{\sum_{i=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac1{2^{n+1}}}_{=\frac12}$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying my question! How do you get the last step? I mean the last term: $$ [ 1/(2^(n+1) ] * (2^(n+1) - 2^n -1) $$ I am wondering if that term is minor or equal to he difference between the sums in the first hand of the inequality. DO you have any other hint? 

Thanks again!

Comment: First notice that $2^{n+1}=2\times 2^n$ so the number of terms in the last sum is $2^n=\frac12\times 2^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}}\frac{1}{i}+\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{i} \\ = \sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}}\frac{1}{i}+\left(\frac{1}{2^k+1}+\frac{1}{2^k+1} \ldots +\frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1}+ \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right) \\ \geq \sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}}\frac{1}{i}+\left(\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \ldots +\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}+ \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right)$$ The "greater than or equal to" is true because you are making the denominators larger. Next, you know you are adding up $2^k$ quantities of  $\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ since $2^{k+1}-2^{k} = 2^k(2-1) = 2^k$. Hence $$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}}\frac{1}{i}+\left(\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \ldots +\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}+ \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}}\frac{1}{i}+2^k\left(\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right) \\ = \sum_{i=1}^{2^{k}}\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{2}$$ Now apply the induction hypothesis and do some algebra to get your result!

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+....+\frac{1}{2^n}=\\\frac{1}{1}\\+\frac{1}{2}\\+(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4})\\+(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8})\\+...\\+(\frac{1}{2^n+1}+\frac{1}{2^n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n+2^n})$$now see

$$\frac{1}{1}\\+\frac{1}{2}\\+(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4})>(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4})\\+(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8})>(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8})\\+...\\+(\frac{1}{2^n+1}+\frac{1}{2^n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2^n+2^n})>(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}+....\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$$so $$A>1+\frac{1}{2}+2\frac{1}{4}+4\frac{1}{8}+...\\A>1+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}....)\\A>1+\frac{n}{2}$$